# Use of Greek language without \textlatin{} \textgreek{} each word

Tags: babel, greek

I am writing a thesis in Latex,using the babel library `\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}`
But using `\textlatin` and `\textgreek` in every word is very frustrating.
I tried using polyglosia library `\usepackage{fontspec,xgreek,polyglossia}`
but i got errors in every compiler.
Is there some way to use both texts without changing each word?

Code of main below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[LGR]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,greek]{babel}
\newcommand{\en}{\selectlanguage{english}}
\newcommand{\gr}{\selectlanguage{greek}}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}
\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{kmath,kerkis}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
% Redefine plain style, which is used for titlepage and chapter beginnings
% From https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/30230/828
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
    \fancyhf{}%
    \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}%
}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\rhead{ \chaptername }
\lhead{Έξυπνο Σπίτι}
\rfoot{\thepage}
\graphicspath{{../PICS/}}

\def\tl{\textlatin}
\def\tg{\textgreek}

\begin{document}
\include{cover}
\title{Υλοποίηση  ενός προσωπικού ψηφιακού βοηθού μέσω \textlatin{open-source} εφαρμογών}
\author{ΧΑΤΖΟΓΛΟΥ ΚΩΣΤΑΣ \\
\today
\href{mailto:empty@auth.gr}{\tl{empty@auth.gr}}}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents

\thispagestyle{empty}
\include{DOCUMENT/Εισαγωγή}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\appendix
\include{acronyms}

\selectlanguage{english}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{IEEEabrv,references}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just found my answer in this topic
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46/how-do-i-use-an-opentype-font-with-my-latex-document

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please always provide a small document example, which reproduce your problem. We cant compile your document because we haven't your files which you include in document.

Comment: I switching to LuaLaTeX is an option, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529663/unicode-multi-alphabet-dictionary/529714#529714 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/523610/korean-symbols-in-latex/524636#524636 .

Answer (score 4):

My preferred solution is to use `babel` in LuaLaTeX, which can automatically detect the script you’re using and change fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nil]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\babelprovide[import=el, main, onchar=ids fonts]{greek} % can also do import=el-polyton
\babelprovide[import, onchar=ids fonts]{english}

\babelfont{rm}
          [Language=Default, Color=DarkGreen]{CMU Serif}
\babelfont[english]{rm}
          [Language=Default, Color=NavyBlue]{CMU Serif}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Language=Default]{CMU Sans Serif}
\babelfont{tt}
          [Language=Default]{CMU Typewriter Text}

\begin{document}
\title{Υλοποίηση ενός προσωπικού ψηφιακού βοηθού μέσω open-source εφαρμογών}
\author{ΧΑΤΖΟΓΛΟΥ ΚΩΣΤΑΣ}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Έξυπνο Σπίτι}

Some text in English and Ελληνικά.

\end{document}
```

[image]

I chose the CMU fonts as an example because they require the `Script=Greek` font feature to work properly, but I also, purely for testing, gave Greek and English different colors.

**This is actually more complicated than necessary.** In practice, the Latin and Greek scripts are similar enough that you could get away with using the same Unicode font for both.  The downside is, you would not get proper hyphenation for the second language.

XeLaTeX does not support `onchar=`, but you can try to do this with the (unmaintained and buggy) package `ucharclasses`.

```
\documentclass[english, greek]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage[Latin, Greek]{ucharclasses}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\babelfont{rm}
          [Language=Default, Color=DarkGreen]{CMU Serif}
\babelfont[english]{rm}
          [Language=Default, Color=NavyBlue]{CMU Serif}
\babelfont{sf}
          [Language=Default]{CMU Sans Serif}
\babelfont{tt}
          [Language=Default]{CMU Typewriter Text}

\setTransitionTo{BasicLatin}{\begin{otherlanguage}{english}}
\setTransitionFrom{BasicLatin}{\end{otherlanguage}}

\begin{document}
\title{Υλοποίηση ενός προσωπικού ψηφιακού βοηθού μέσω open-source εφαρμογών}
\author{ΧΑΤΖΟΓΛΟΥ ΚΩΣΤΑΣ}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Έξυπνο Σπίτι}

Some text in English and Ελληνικά.

\end{document}
```

My recommendation is to use LuaLaTeX when you can and 8-bit font encodings from last century when you’re forced to, but if you’re forced to, here’s how.

```
\documentclass[english, greek]{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018.
\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\title{Υλοποίηση ενός προσωπικού ψηφιακού βοηθού μέσω open-source εφαρμογών}
\author{ΧΑΤΖΟΓΛΟΥ ΚΩΣΤΑΣ}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Έξυπνο Σπίτι}

Some text in English and Ελληνικά.

\end{document}
```

Unlike the newer engines, this solution will only change the font, not load Greek or English hyphenation patterns.  If you are sprinkling in only a few English words, this should not be too much of a problem.  IF you do need to actually switch the `babel` language tag, for example because you need to write full sentences in English that hyphenate properly, you can use `\foreignlanguage{english}{Some text}` or `\begin{otherlanguage}{english}`.

If you do want to pair different font families for English and Greek in PDFTeX, you can do this with `\substitutefont`.  This example uses TeX Gyre Termes for English and Tempora for Greek.

```
\documentclass[english, greek]{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % The default since 2018.
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{tgtermes}
\usepackage{substitutefont}

\substitutefont{LGR}{\rmdefault}{Tempora-TLF}

\begin{document}
\title{Υλοποίηση ενός προσωπικού ψηφιακού βοηθού μέσω open-source εφαρμογών}
\author{ΧΑΤΖΟΓΛΟΥ ΚΩΣΤΑΣ}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Έξυπνο Σπίτι}

Some text in English and Ελληνικά.

\end{document}
```

Also note that PDFTeX supports only precomposed characters, not combining accents.

Comment: what is `nil` in `\usepackage[nil]{babel}`? Is it needed?

Comment: @Urel Not really. The `nil` option tells `babel` not to bother loading a default main language. I threw that in because I’d be loading a new main language momentarily, but it only saves a fraction of a second on a modern computer.

Comment: thanks! And what does `import=el`? I didn't find anything in the documentation

Comment: @Urel That tells `babel` to load the language data from the  file `babel-el.ini`, rather than `greek.ldf`. For polytonic Greek, `import=el-polyton`. It’s in section 1.13 of the Babel manual.

Comment: @Urel If you have `\babelprovide[onchar=fonts ids]{greek}`, I believe it will still work.