# How to produce this Greek word with \textgreek

Tags: typography, greek

Here is a word I am trying to produce with textgreek:

[image]

So far, I have

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{\begingroup\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont#1\endgroup}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Huge
\textbf{\textgreek{peirathoion}}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]

As you can see, the ``alpha'' does not appear as an `a'; and, there is no mark under the first` o' as the original picture indicates.

Can anyone provide help in modifying the code so that the original word is produced?

Thank you.

Comment: The word is actually πειρατήριον (gang of pirates); the letter following the eta is a rho (and you're missing an accent).

Comment: Try: https://ctan.org/pkg/betababel

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\textgreek{πειρατήριον}
\end{document}  `

Answer (score 2):

One alternative is to enter it as Unicode:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{textalpha}
\usepackage[greek,english]{babel}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\Huge
πειρατήριον
\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern font sample]

You can do the same in LuaTeX or XeTeX by loading a font that supports Greek, such as `\usepackage{newcomputermodern}` or `\usepackage{libertinus}`.

If you want to use the Latin alphabet as your input method, you want either `betababel` or `teubner`.  I also wrote a beta-code input method for XeTeX a little while back.  To change fonts or enable full hyphenation whenever TeX sees Greek letters [takes slightly more work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579780/use-of-greek-language-without-textlatin-textgreek-each-word/579813#579813)