# Polyglossia package and hyphenation in second language (not the default)

Tags: hyphenation, polyglossia

Is there any global command to fix the problem of second language hyphenation ?

The code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{Thesis}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{CMU Serif}
\setsansfont{CMU Sans Serif}
\newfontfamily{\greekfont}{CMU Serif}
\newfontfamily{\greekfontsf}{CMU Sans Serif}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguages{english}

\begin{document}
Ένα παρόμοιο πρόβλημα που συναντάτε συχνά στην βιβλιογραφία είναι 
το πρόβλημα της "Πρότασης Κριτικών για Αξιολόγηση Επιστημονικών 
Άρθρων" (Paper Reviewer Recommendation Problem) ή αλλιώς "Ανάθεση 
Κριτικού" (Reviewer Assignment Problem). Όπως φαίνεται και από το 
όνομα του προβλήματος ο βασικός σκοπός του είναι, με κάποιον 
αυτόματο τρόπο, να βρεθούν και να προταθούν σχετικοί κριτές για 
την αξιολόγηση ενός επιστημονικού άρθρου με βάση πιθανόν κάποιο 
γνωστικό αντικείμενο.
\end{document}
```

and the result is this:

[image]

I know that there is topic commands to fix the problem such as:

`\foreignlanguage{english}{}`

but I am asking for a global solution.

Comment: Please post a minimum complete code that reproduce the output. From `\documentclass` to `\end{document}`.

Comment: @SimonDispa the code is a lot of lines. The main problem is in those lines I uploaded, because they are the lines that I declare the language.

Comment: Does [this work for you?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/579813/61644)